# CSS drop down menu doesn't work properly in Google Chrome (the submenus disappear on hover)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm having problems with a small CSS drop down menu (for choosing languages) that won't work properly in Chrome (it works fine in IE and Firefox). The language choices disappear when hovering them – but only sometimes. There doesn't seem to be any logic really. I would appreciate any help.

The menu can be seen on this test page in the upper right corner: http://www.hypro.se/test

Edit: I couldn't solve the issue but I decided to use Polyglot Language Switcher instead: http://www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2

My CSS:

```
#dropdown {
 width: 110px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 background: #222;
 font: 13px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 9999999;
}
#dropdown li {
 width: 110px;
 height: 24px;
 float: left;
 background: #222;
 list-style: none;
 font: 13px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 0;
}
#dropdown li:hover {
 background: #000;
}
#dropdown li a {
 font: 13px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#dropdown ul {
 background: #222;
 display: none;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 24px;
 float: left;
 z-index: 9999;
}
#dropdown li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
.globe {
    position: relative;
    left: 6px;
    top: 4px;
}
.choose_language {
    position: relative;
    left: 12px;
    top: 1px;
}
.flag {
 padding-left: 5px;
}
.language {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: -7px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
      <nav id="dropdown">
        <li><span class="globe"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_globe.png" alt="Choose language" title="Choose language"/></span><span class="choose_language">Choose language</span>
          <ul>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=swe" lang="sv" hreflang="sv"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_sweden.png" alt="Svenska" title="Svenska"/></span><span class="language">Svenska</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=fin" lang="fi" hreflang="fi"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_finland.png" alt="Suomi" title="Suomi"/></span><span class="language">Suomi</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=eng" lang="en" hreflang="en"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_england.png" alt="English" title="English"/></span><span class="language">English</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=ger" lang="de" hreflang="de"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_germany.png" alt="Deutsch" title="Deutsch"/></span><span class="language">Deutsch</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=fra" lang="fr" hreflang="fr"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_france.png" alt="Le Français" title="Le Français"/></span><span class="language">Le Français</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=esp" lang="es" hreflang="es"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_spain.png" alt="Español" title="Español"/></span><span class="language">Español</span></li></a>
            <a href="?p=index&lang=ita" lang="it" hreflang="it"><li><span class="flag"><img src="bilder/hemsida/icon_italy.png" alt="Italiano" title="Italiano"/></span><span class="language">Italiano</span></li></a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </nav>
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue, but I guess setting `z-index` on selection menu to a high value might resolve your problem

Comment: I've tried setting z-index to 9999999 on everything in the menu but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug in the new Chrome version 43. It started happening to us when we upgraded, previously v42 worked fine. In our framework (ExtJS v4.2) it would happen when we hovered to a submenu; the submenu appeared and then dissappeared on the `mouseleave` event of the main menu item. We found a patch for it on the Sencha forum if anyone is experiencing the same:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301116-Submenus-disappear-in-Chrome-43-beta

which appears to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

Add z index css Properties  in sub menu

## dropdown li:hover ul {

display: inline-block;
z-index: 9999999;
right:0px;
}

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: working fine on my system. what is your chrome version?

Comment: I had the same issue with my google chrome version Version 41.0.2272.101 m. When i downgraded it to some 36. versions it worked  (But this page is working fine on my 41.0.2272.101 m version)

Comment: I've asked friends to help me check and together we've tried at least ten different computers, and sometimes even the same browser version works on one computer but not another – for example 41.0.2272.101.